# jQuery UI accordion: expand if focused by url else active false

Tags: jquery, user-interface, select, accordion

I have a jQuery UI accordion working fine with all collapsed on initial page load however I want to add a step so that people can link directly to one of the h3 in my accordion and have that item expanded on load.  What code can I add so that people can link directly to an article and have that article expand on load?  Ex. http://example.com/#456

Below is my current setup:

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3 id="123">title</h3>
    <div>article</div>
  <h3 id="456">title</h3>
    <div>article</div>
  <h3 id="789">title</h3>
    <div>article</div>
</div>
<script>
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({heightStyle: 'content', collapsible: true, active: false});
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. However, accordions require the Header to have an anchor that you are navigating to through its navigation boolean parameter.

You can implement it like this

html

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#item1">Item 1</a></h3>
      <div>article</div>
    <h3><a href="#item2">Item 2</a></h3>
      <div>article</div>
    <h3><a href="#item3">Item 3</a></h3>
      <div>article</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3", navigation: true });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion makes sense.  I mirrored your suggestion and multiple variants of it but couldn't get it to work.  I'm thinking that I have to bind a click or something?  In plain English I would say 'if id is focused via URL then activate selected id'.  I'm not sure that's possible but still looking.  Thanks jrizzle88.